# Checking a tensor product (Yang Baxter Equation)

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, tensors

I want to verify that a matrix $R$ satisfies this equation 
$$
\left(R\otimes id\right)\left(id\otimes R\right)\left(R\otimes id\right)=\left(id\otimes R\right)\left(R\otimes id\right)\left(id\otimes R\right)
$$
Are this lines correct?

```
R = ({{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, q}, {0, 0, q, 1 - q^2}});
id = IdentityMatrix[4];
r1 = KroneckerProduct[id, R]; 
r2 = KroneckerProduct[R, id]; 
r1.r2.r1 - r2.r1.r2 // MatrixForm
```

Of course the matrix R would be the one to check. The result in a positive case of course should be the zero matrix. Is the syntax correct?

Comment: What about using `TensorProduct`?

Comment: is it different?

Comment: Doesn't work with TensorProduct

Comment: Why do you believe that this identity should be correct? The definitions of `R` and `id` are also missing.

Comment: It's related to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2684140/definition-of-the-quantum-plane-and-the-yang-baxter-equation?noredirect=1#comment5543431_2684140

Comment: I didn't want to cross-post that's why I didn't write the background context

Comment: Aha. You know that "it doesn't seem to work" is very useless problem description, do you? Moreover, this is not necessarily a problem with Mathematica but with the matrix `R`...

Comment: Please let's stick to the question I posted. I'm not asking if this particular matrix satisfies the YBE, I'm asking if the syntax to check it is correct

Comment: You know, context _is_ important...

Answer (score 1):

What is you definition of the multiplication in $(A \otimes B) \cdot (C \otimes D)$? Probably it does not coincide with Mathematica's `Dot`.
Honestly, I am not entirely sure what `KroneckerProduct` does with matrices and how this interacts with `Dot` (personally, I use `KroneckerProduct` solely for vector-vector pairs). So I try to boil things down to `TensorProduct` and `TensorContract`.

As can be read off from the documentation, `Dot` merely contracts the last slot of the first argument with the first slot of the second argument. So that would be

$$(A \otimes B) . (C \otimes D) = A \otimes (B \cdot C) \otimes D.$$

In Mathematica syntax, `Dot` is equivalent on pairs of 4-tensors to the following function:

```
dot[S_?(TensorRank[#] == 4 &), T_?(TensorRank[#] == 4 &)] := 
  TensorContract[S\[TensorProduct]T, {4, 5}];
```

This is why $(A \otimes B) . (C \otimes D)$ is a tensor of rank 6 and not of rank 4.

I guess you think in terms of matrix algebras, so maybe you mean

$$(A \otimes B) \cdot (C \otimes D) = (A \cdot C) \otimes (B \cdot D).$$

I think the desired product can be expressed unambiguously by the following function:

```
newdot[S_?(TensorRank[#] == 4 &), T_?(TensorRank[#] == 4 &)] := 
  TensorContract[S\[TensorProduct]T, {2, 5, 4, 7}];
```

Comment: thank you, could you add also the correct syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure I followed you until the end... I mean what is the problem if I first calculate the matrices KroneckerProduct and then I multiply them?

Comment: Sorry about the mess with `KroneckerProduct`. I edited the post with hopefully correct code.